# KendoUI Slider, unequal steps

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a KendoUI slider and need it to stop on uneven numbers. I'd like the slider to stop at 24, 49, 73, and 97. Therefore I can't set the step to 25, since sometimes it's 24. I don't see anything in the documentation that will let me do this. Any geniuses out there want to help me tackle this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague.
But you can capture the change event and either increase or decrease by one if value is even.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UH56d/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="equalizer">
        <input class="eqSlider" value="15" />
    </div>
</div>


var slider = $(".eqSlider").kendoSlider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    smallStep: 1,
    largeStep: 2,
    change:SlideFunc,
    showButtons: false
});

function SlideFunc(e) {
    //var sliderValue = slider.value();
    var value = e.value;
    var modu = value % 2;
    if(modu == 0 && value > 1) {
        e.value = value - 1;
    }
}
```